# Need some best possible suggestion on ECS POC

Tags: containers, amazon-ecs

I have started with POC on ECS just wanna mention I got a good exposure on docker engine and compose however started with ECS recently. I want to containerize more than 50 micro-services however I am looking for a best possible way to accomplish this. Can someone advise how can I start in a best possible manner ?

Comment: Asking what is the "best possible" thing is really just soliciting opinions, since multiple possible ways of doing things exist for a reason. If one way was objectively better than every other, in all circumstances, then the other ways wouldn't have a reason to exist. As it is your question is too vague, and opinionated for this site. Please try to ask more focused questions.

Comment: @MarkB yeah you are right although I was able to find the answer however I have more clear question which I am gonna ask in the  next question ....Thanks